# Connected sets explanation

Tags: general-topology

An equivalent definition of connected sets is that:

> A topological space $D$ is connected if it is **not possible** to to find in $D$ a strict subset $D_0$, such that $D_0$ is both open and closed.

My question is suppose we have a connected open set $D$ and there is a strict subset $D_0$ such that $D_0$ is open then the complement of $D_0$ is a closed set which is $D_0^c=D\setminus D_0$ therefore, $D_0^c$ is both open and closed. Here lies my confusion. I would appreciate if someone to shed some light on this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On *any* non-empty topological space $D$ there is a strict subset which is both open and closed: $\emptyset$.

Comment: Besides: why to use the [tag:elementary-set-theory] tag on a [tag:general-topology] question?

Comment: Yeah I should have used the other tag, however I thought it would be a trival topic in set theory. My bad

Comment: I am familiar about the null set, however my confusion arises from the argument that even in connected set one can find a closed and open set (apart from the null set).

Comment: Why is $D_0^C$ open?

Comment: @FranCruz, good point, I think I found my answer.  However, is it possible to create an open and connected set such that $D=D_1\bigcup D_2$ where $D_1, D_2$ are open and $D_1\bigcap D_2=\emptyset$ ?

Comment: @user591745 Pick $D_1 = D$ and $D_2 = \emptyset$. No examples exist when both sets are nonempty.

Comment: @FranCruz Thanks, this was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.

Answer (score 1):

$D_0^\complement$ is open in $D$ iff its complement in $D$, which is $D_0$ again, is **closed**. But you've only assumed that $D_0$ is open. So the conclusion does *not* follow.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get the complete picture now.